# Gravitational Slingshot

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, space-mission

If a spacecraft slingshots around a planet P (with escape velocity $V$) at an angle $\theta$, I understand that the resulting velocity will be

$$v_{2}=(v_{1}+2u)\sqrt{1-\frac{4uv_{1}(1-\cos\theta)}{(v_{1}+2u)^{2}}}.$$

However, this equation does not involve the mass of the assisting planet, nor the distance/altitude from which the spacecraft must slingshot from.

After reading the answer to

[To what extent could a single Triton flyby slow down a direct Hohmann transfer to Neptune for NOI?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6504/),

I have a few questions:

- How is the formula for the bent angle and eccentricity derived?
- What exactly is the geometry behind the maneuver? More specifically, where does the hyperbola come from?
- How is the formula for the turning angle, given by

$$\delta =2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac {1}{1+\dfrac{ {r}_{p}v_{\infty}^{2}}{\mu}}\right),$$

derived?

Please note that I'm a high school student with a knowledge of Calculus I & II, and that visual diagrams would be greatly helpful.